# AWS changes the port number to name

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, port, iptables

AWS automatically changes the well known port numbers to name.
For example 554 to rtsp.

When I am installing iptable rules, with the port number as 554, its getting changed to rtsp. This is creating problem when searching because my program passes 554 as parameter.

How to make sure that the AWS doesn't change the number to name ?

[image]
In the picture we can see the dpt:rtsp, which actually should be dpt:554.

Comment: I don't think there is anything AWS specific about this. This is entirely a Linux/IPTables question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `iptables --list -n`?  The `-n` prints "numeric output of addresses and ports."